# how geofencing can be more accurate than checking location at regular intervals?

Tags: android, android-location, android-geofence, android-fusedlocation

I don't understand how `geofencing` can be more accurate than checking location at regular intervals (https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/background-location-updates-android-o/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#6) ? Because let say I m at position x and i set a geofence of 250m, as soon as the user get out of this geofence, i store the new position and then i set a new geofence of 250m and etc.

Is this not at the end the same than doing `mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates` with a `smallestDisplacement` of 250m ? I don't understand how geofence will use less battery than `mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates`

Answer (score 1):

From the link you posted, I don't believe they mean that geofencing is more accurate than checking at regular intervals with location services. The use case is only for a specific area of interest. It also states that geofencing provides a more performant way to "get these notifications". This is just saying that the api provides notifications when a user enters or exits an area.

Here's a use case:

A user is walking around the city and is within 500 meters of a Starbucks. Starbucks app sends a notification with a deal to the user for a discounted drink when they enter the geofence (within 500 meters). This way, Starbucks doesn't track the user constantly to see if they are close to one of their stores.

Comment: but explain me, If the "system" don't track constantly the location of the user, how he can know you enter/exit a geofence ? so why using geofence will use less battery ?

Comment: The sample geofence project in the link you provided gives a pretty good example. They use a combination of BroadcastReceiver and PendingIntent to launch a background service to deliver a location update. Once the update is delivered, the process and everything with it terminates. This consumes less battery than maintaining a foreground service to keep location updates active.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand how geofencing can be more accurate than checking location at regular intervals

Who said that geofencing is  more accurate than checking location? Constantly requesting location e.g. at 1Hz pace is super accurate and the only more accurate method would be doing the same at 100Hz.

But you will slaughter the battery in about an hour or so.

Geofences **tries** to act as much accurate not eating your device battery much. If it works? Go figure.